# How to insert a max value plus one in mysql in opencart

Tags: mysql, opencart

I have the following:

**Model File**

```
$max = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX( sort ) FROM lc_menu");
print_r($max);
```

**Printed Values**

```
stdClass Object ( [num_rows] => 1 [row] => Array ( [MAX( sort )] => 64 )
[rows] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [MAX( sort )] => 64 ) ) )
```

How can I insert `max+1` in MySQL query?

Comment: Where do you want to insert `max + 1`???

Comment: in my sql query

Comment: $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "menu SET menuname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['menuname']) . "',start_date = '" . $this->db->escape($data['start_date']) . "',start_time = '" . $this->db->escape($data['start_time']) . "',end_date = '" . $this->db->escape($data['end_date']) . "',end_time = '" . $this->db->escape($data['end_time']) . "',link_value = '" . $this->db->escape($data['link_value']) . "',link = '" . $this->db->escape($alpha['link']) . "'");

Comment: Onto which field do you want to insert `max + 1`??

Comment: sort= '" .$max +1  . "

Comment: Where is that field???

Comment: Array ( [MAX( sort )] => 64 ) I am getting $max value like this then how can i insert

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery:

```
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO ' . DB_PREFIX . ' menu SET
menuname = "$this->db->escape($data['menuname'])",
start_date = "$this->db->escape($data['start_date'])",
start_time = "$this->db->escape($data['start_time'])",
end_date = "$this->db->escape($data['end_date'])",
end_time = "$this->db->escape($data['end_time'])",
link_value = "$this->db->escape($data['link_value'])",
link = "$this->db->escape($alpha['link'])",
sort = ((SELECT MAX(sort) FROM lc_menu) + 1)');
```

Comment: I need to insert a max value+1 in my table

Comment: @prathap: on which table, tell me your table name, friend!

Comment: My Friend Table Name menu with DB_prefix

Comment: @prathap: i got it.

Comment: Okay Please let my know my friend

Comment: Please, provide the result that you've got when you trying to insert???